# Recursve function return error 500

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I create recursive function to walk on `$allCategories` array, but it gives me Error 500. Error log at `/var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.error.log` and display all errors not showing anything except Notices. What i'm doing wrong?

`$categoryArray = $this->searchNodes($allCategories,$category->id);`

```
public function searchNodes($tree,$search_id){  
    foreach($tree as $array){
            if($array['id_category'] == $search_id){
                return $array;
            } else{
                if(array_key_exists('children', $array))
                    $childrenNodes = $this->searchNodes($array['children'],$search_id);
                    if($childrenNodes != false){
                        return $childrenNodes;
                    }
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A http status 500 (internal server error) will _always_ result in an entry in the http servers error log file. You must be monitoring the wrong file. (unless you manually output that status...)

Comment: This error may be because of XDebug extension limitation. you can try after adding `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);` in your php code or update xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200 in php.ini file. `200` may increase based on the nested limit. We need exact error to rectify.

Comment: Except all PHP Notice there is something weird in log :
`[Thu Jun 29 13:58:24.863222 2017] [core:error] [pid 2444] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:56868] End of script output before headers: index.php
`
What it means?

Comment: You need to Google that error; there are many hits for it ^ - Too many actually.

Comment: Google said that my PHP interpreter crashed. If i don't use this recursive function my script work fine, can it be Stack Overflow error or something? I enable log repporting in PHP configuration file, but it's empty. `xdebug.max_nesting_level` is set to `1000000`